# How to view I/O statistics in DB2

Tags: performance, db2

In Sybase, one can view the I/O statistics of a query using the following:

```
set noexec on
set statistics io on
```

This allows one to see the total logical I/O for a query without actually executing it. Is there an equivalent sort of command for DB2?

Answer (score 0):

The EXPLAIN statement may provide some of what you want (I'm afraid I don't have actual use details), or Visual Explain if you have access to that.

Explain:
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.admin.doc/doc/r0001001.htm

Comment: Visual Explain because I can't add two links in the same post:
http://www.devx.com/getHelpOn/10MinuteSolution/16567/1954